# Can a SharePoint Hosted Add-in call a public web API (like Google Maps or Open Weather)?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-hosted-app

Assuming, it's a pure JavaScript page/app with no server-side rendering required...

Can a SharePoint Hosted Add-in call a public web API (like Google Maps or Open Weather)? Or would this make it a Provider Hosted Add-in?

What if it's calling a public web API that you "own" -- does this now become a Provider Hosted Add-in? I'm a little confused on the differences between the two.

Thanks!